# How to compare two columns of a row with same two columns of other row using awk? Can I also get the count the identical rows

Tags: awk, count, string-comparison

```
Oct 7     02:55:20       123.111.44.77     99        123.111.66.91 12345    
Oct 7     02:58:10       123.111.44.77     99        123.111.66.98 48575   
Oct 7     02:05:40       123.111.44.77     99        123.111.66.99 09876   
Oct 7     02:50:40       123.111.44.77     99        123.111.66.99 56743    
Oct 7     02:53:00       123.111.44.77     99        123.111.66.12 98475   
Oct 7     02:58:00       123.111.44.77     99        123.111.66.98 12489
```

This is the input.

The required output is:

```
     123.111.44.77       123.111.66.99 (2)     
     123.111.44.77       123.111.66.98 (2)
```

How can I do it using AWK?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: dont use image, post your input

Comment: You an format your examples as tables - just put four spaces in front of each line of the table and it will look fine.

Comment: Please don't put the examples in a comment - put them in the question.

Comment: Thank you e0k for editing the question.

Comment: If there are identical IP addresses (sixth column), which date do you print?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, but you forgot to post your code. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Good luck.

Comment: Good question e0k. I have edited the question, because date was not so important in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AWK,

```
$ awk '{c[$6]++}c[$6]>1{d[$6]=$4}END{for(x in d)printf "%s\t%s (%s)\n",d[x],x,c[x]}' infile
```

This produces

```
123.111.44.77   123.111.66.99 (2)
123.111.44.77   123.111.66.98 (2)
```

You can tweak the output format.  I have separated the first two fields with a tab and the second and third (the count) with a single space.  Your sample output looked a bit like this.

The above counts the occurrences of the address on the right (column 6) and prints those that occur more than once along with the the address on the left (column 4) from the last occurrence (along with the tally in parentheses).  On further thought, this may not be exactly what you wanted.  (If it is, great!)

---

If you want to count *pairings* of the left and right addresses (columns 4 and 6), try something like

```
$ awk '{c[$4"\t"$6]++}END{for(x in c)printf "%s (%d)\n",x,c[x]}' infile
```

This will print every pairing with a tally of the number of occurrences in parentheses.  If you only want the pairings that occur more than once, then add the `if` condition:

```
$ awk '{c[$4"\t"$6]++}END{for(x in c)if (c[x]>1){printf "%s (%d)\n",x,c[x]}}' infile
```

Please note that all of these assume the addresses you want are in columns 4 and 6.  They perform no regular expression checking, etc., to see if they actually look like addresses.